# Android ACRA - Bearer Authentication

Tags: android, kotlin, acra

Hello I implemented ACRA error repporting to my project (https://github.com/ACRA/acra) and it works. But I have one problem, is it possible to specify authentication in HTTP Sender other than the basic one? I need to send HTTP request with Bearer authentication. Is it possible somehow with ACRA or should I use something else? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well I was reading bunch of articles and documentations and I did not find any solution. But I strongly recommend anyone who wants to use some crash logging to use Crashlytics from Firebase (https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics). I removed ACRA from project and started to use Crashlytics and I can't complain.